# How can I make an animated button?

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

I have looked but couldn't find anything that worked. I'm very much a beginner with all this so I apologize if it's a simple question.

I want to create a button in C# for Android (Monodroid) that when clicked shows a "pressed state" so the user is aware the button has been used.

How do I do this? I have two images in my drawables folder which are .png files from Photoshop - how can I incorporate this into my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you use a `State List`. An XML file that references different bitmap graphics for different states (for example, to use a different image when a button is pressed). Creates a StateListDrawable. Perhaps see the [State List documentation](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Widget.Button).

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do this in android is to set the background of the button to resource to point to a state list drawable 
[StateList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) that contains states for pressed and normal and points to the correct image for each state.

I have no knowledge of monodroid so I don't know if you can do this with it or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have an example with two states:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />
    <item
         android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />
</selector>
```